# Task Created When Email Alert Triggered By WFR

Tags: visualforce, tasks, email-alert

I have a time-based WFR on the Account object that sends out an Email alert 2 days after a date that is stamped by Case records.  The email alert template is made up of a visualforce page that groups cases of similar characteristics.  This works fantastic, but the issue is I don't know that an email was sent. Does anyone know how I can create a Task once the email alert is sent?  The tricky part is that I need to pull in the cases that were included in the email alert, plus the contacts that are listed as fields on the Account record.

Comment: You want the Task to memorialize the cases+contacts used within the body of the time-based workflow's email alert?  This is a hard problem unless you persist those IDs in some SObject field associate or related to the target workflow object

Answer (score 1):

You could do your custom task creation in a flow. If you do it that way, you can add a checkbox to your account record that also gets flipped when the email goes out. Then you can have a Process watch for that flag being flipped and then execute your Flow which will then do your task work or anything else you may want to do when the time based workflow fires. Just make sure you uncheck that checkbox as part of your Flow so the next time the time dependent action fires, it won't still be checked from the last time the action fired.